# Done button in full screen video player in iOS does not close video

Tags: ios

In my application, when a button is clicked the full screen video player in iOS open playing a video file. However, when I click Done the player does not close.

Comment: How do you present the `MPMoviewPlayerViewController`(?). Please provide some code.

Comment: I think its issue with delegate methods. You are not calling or adding delegate methods properly

Comment: Possible duplicate [of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773338/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-done-button-is-not-removing-the-player)